# Printing Elements from Repeaters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, repeater

So I am brand new to programming in both Javascript and just started working with QA testing. My goal right now is fairly simple. I want to make sure that all elements are loaded in the repeater before I make my selection from the list. I wanted to wait until the first and last element were present before proceeding with my test.

I know there are probably better ways to do this, feel free to throw suggestions at me. I've been looking around online and found code snippets detailing how to print to the console the values of elements within repeaters.

I figured I'd first just try to print out the first and last element to make sure I was getting them correctly. I did this:

```
var repeaterElements = element.all(by.repeater(repeaterObj));
var text = repeaterElements.first().toString();
console.log(text);
```

My goal being just to simply print the first element. However I got it to print [object Object] instead. Am I reasoning through this incorrectly? I thought that '.first( )' would give me the first element within the repeater!

-hopper

Comment: I think if you take `.toString()` off you will output the object as you intended.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are wanting, but I think this is it. This should go through a repeater, select all elements, get the text of those elements and console it out. If you are actually going to be doing anything other than consoling, remember to keep your promises!

```
element.all(by.repeater(repeaterObj)).each(function(obj){
  obj.getText().then(function(text){
      console.log(text)
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! This was exactly what I was trying to do. I'm still trying to get a firm grasp of JS, could you explain how .each() takes in a function? 

In other words, I'm confused about how .each() knows where this 'obj' is coming from. Similarly, where is the parameter 'text' passed in for console.log to use? 

Logically it's the resolution of doing obj.getText(), but I guess what I am asking is how does it know to pass that value to the parameter in `.then(function(text){ console.log(text)});` ?

Hopefully that makes sense. I found this question was hard to phrase haha

Comment: The method each is simply a method on the element.all in this case - it takes a function and passes each element into the first argument (I think it takes a second argument as well which would be the index). In the case of getText, it is an available method on the element that is returned from the "each" that returns a promise that we can "then" off of.It may help you to console out the individual elements and you can see what methods are available on those elements.

Comment: Hey I know I'm keeping this thread up a bit longer, but I think it's somewhat related with repeaters so I figured I would ask you. I wanted to write a quick helper function that would wait for the first and last element in a repeater to be visible/fully loaded before clicking on an element. I have:
`var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var repeaterElements = element.all(by.repeater(repeaterObj));

    return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(repeaterElements.first()) && EC.visibilityOf(repeaterElements.last()),5000); `

It seems to work, but I want a correct implementation! :)

Comment: Yes, what you have would work, but I'm not sure EC is needed (depends on what you're doing) and I also don't think you need to wait for 'first and last', because I would be surprised if element.all didn't automatically wait for all elements. I think the below would work and be more succinct:

`return browser.wait(element.all(by.repeater(repeaterObj)).isDisplayed()),5000);`

Also, I'd be surprised if you needed to do this at all...most of the time you should just be able to do the above without a wait at all. Unless maybe you are generating the repeater without a state change?